# WordPress Query String: get_posts('cat=5') vs WP_Query( 'cat=5') vs URL: /site/?cat=5

Tags: wp-query, urls, query-string

We can filter our posts with a URL query string:
`http://mysite.com/?cat=5`

We can also use a similar syntax for `get_posts('cat=5')` and `new WP_Query('cat=5')`.**   `get_posts('param=value');` just passes the string to `new WP_Query('param=value');`, so it follows that these work the same.

While these all seem to have the same syntax, the URL query string supports different parameters.

- I don't see `subpost` or `subpost_id` documented anywhere in the WP_Query class, yet it seems to do something with the URL (although I can't figure out exactly what)
- `category__in` doesn't work with the URL query string.

After much searching, I finally found [this site that lists the supported URL query string variables](http://gabrielkoen.com/2011/09/01/wordpress-defaultquery-variables-parameters/), but not sure what all of them do.

Where is the documentation for these URL query string variables?

WP_Query supports many more parameters that don't seem to be supported in the URL query.  Why doesn't the URL query string just get passed directly to WP_Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at official [`Query vars`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars). You will see two columns and by then you will get why `category__in doesn't work with the URL query string`. (basically, the private keywords works only if you specify them in wp_query or so...)

About `subpost`, I am not a hundred percent sure, what it is. In the whole WP_Query it is mentioned only with attachments, take a [look](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1485).

Comment: ty, never seen that page :/